# WPML and Yoast SEO setup on a wordpress site is not working properly

Tags: plugin-wp-seo-yoast, plugin-wpml, google-search

I'm stuck with WPML+Yoast SEO on a website everything is translated in 2 languages even in page source the description and title is translated but in google searches google is messing up like for a spanish user it should show the spanish title and description.

Maybe due to canonical and alternate tags its not honoring the request? Can anyone help?
[image: UPDATED sitemap submitted]
[image: Source]
[image: Google Search for a spain based user]

**Update: Have submitted new sitemap but still in google searches its the same output**

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps Google is just showing an older index (the site got indexed before you set up your Yoast translations). Add the site as a property to the Google Search Console and request re-indexing manually. Also, fix any warnings and errors Google displays if there are any.

Comment: Yeah i already done adding that property to search console, i think it would be better to re index and maybe it will be better. i will keep posted.

Comment: Keep in mind that this is a process that may take couple of days (sometimes even weeks) to complete.

Comment: also i just saw that google search console had https://shibaku.ch/sitemap.xml instead the yoast generated sitemap which was https://shibaku.ch/sitemap_index.xml

Comment: **Update: Have submitted new sitemap but still in google searches its the same output**

Comment: Can you guide? Still the issue is same

Answer (score 1):

When have you done the translation? Google chaches the information of your site, means a chance of your site take time till google-crawler was there again and noticed the change and write a new chache...so changes can take till some weeks till google shows the new version...

Comment: no sitemap does not mean google do not send crawler and read sites. If there is no sitemap google try to read your sites...takes longer. If you dont want to google crawl you, you have to do notice at robot.txt

Comment: Yes i re submitted the sitemap though secondly i did the translations and submitted the sitemap after that.

Comment: also i just saw that google search console had https://shibaku.ch/sitemap.xml instead the yoast generated sitemap which was https://shibaku.ch/sitemap_index.xml

Comment: **Update: Have submitted new sitemap but still in google searches its the same output**

Comment: Still the issue is same any help?

Comment: As we said before: if you have submitted the new sitemap it takes time till google send crawler, notice new data und write it in their chache...the time depends on your site (how often are changes on your site in the past for example). But it will take days, even to weeks till you see the results.